# Which Eclipse component enables "Deployment Assembly" tab in project properties?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

I have an incomplete installation of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.
Specifically, I miss a "Deployment Assembly" tab in project properties.

Unfortunately, I do not have a technical option to use a light-weight installer and choose "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" from the GUI menu. I also do not like an idea to install each and every component under the "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development" section.

Which component needs to be installed in order to enable the "Deployment Assembly" tab?

Answer (score 0):

This tab is enabled by the "WTP J2EE UI" plug-in from the "Eclipse Web Tools Platform" provider. You can check whether you have it installed by going to <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>About Eclipse SDK</kbd> → <kbd>Installation Details</kbd> → <kbd>Plug-ins</kbd> and searching for `org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui`.

If you first added the project into the workspace and only then installed the plug-in, you may still miss the "Deployment Assembly" tab. In this case, remove the project from the workspace and add it back. You might also need to remove and add back all related projects.

BTW, the source code of the plug-in is [here](https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.javaee/tree/master/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui) and the "Define packaging structure for this Java EE Application project" text that is visible in the tab is defined [here](https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.javaee/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui/j2ee_ui/org/eclipse/jst/j2ee/internal/ui/preferences/messages.properties).